# Sheloshim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred thirty?

### ?שלושים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 330? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 330, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

We do not need answers of lazy gematria.

Comment: "We do not-need" translates to a word of _gimatriya_ 380, not 330. But good enough.

Comment: @msh210, I'm not sure what you have in mind, but I had a different pun in mind for that part of the sentence.

Comment: I thought you meant not-need = לש (knead).

Comment: @msh210 Oh, yes, except for the "not" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Medrash Raba - Noach](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37457&st=&pgnum=78&hilite=) discussing the makeup of the Ark says that according to the view of Rabbi Yehuda based on the Aruch the Ark was produced from 330 Killin. I think Killin means pieces of wood.

שלש מאות ושלשים קילין

Answer (score -1):

> In Australia, the post war government in Canberra was seeking ways to increase the country’s population. The Immigration Minister Arthur Calwell was sympathetic to the plight of the Jewish refugees and in 1946, three hundred and thirty refugees on board the Hwa Lien left Shanghai bound for Sydney. But it was to be a rocky trip and the Hwa Lien sailed into turbulent political waters. A huge wave of anti- refugee hysteria was sweeping Australia, fuelled by the press and right wing groups like the League of Rights and the RSL.

— ["Shanghai Jews"](http://www.abc.net.au/compass/s712283.htm), an episode of [*Compass*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_%28TV_program%29)